# Animation on Voice Recognition Event A-frame

Tags: javascript, animation, augmented-reality, aframe, voice-recognition

I'm trying to play an animation on a 3D model (gltf model) when a voice command is said, but the animation just play once, the following times that I say the voice command nothing happens.

I was trying is the following code:

```
var ent = document.querySelector('#model3D');
if(voiceCommand.includes("hello")) {
   ent.setAttribute("animation",'property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: false; dur: 5000');
}
```

Could you please give me some ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation plays once, because you add an animation component with `loop: false` - so it's just being attached once, and plays one cycle.

You should use the `startEvents` property and restart the animation whenever you want:

```js
// when the window is clicked
window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // emit the event
  document.querySelector('a-box').emit('foo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <!-- The animation is here from the beginning -->
  <a-box position="0 1 -3" color="#4CC3D9" 
         animation="property: rotation; from: 0 0 0; to: 0 360 0; 
                    loop: false; dur: 400; startEvents: foo"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Piotr! I tried this and I having 2 issues, the first is that the animation is just playing on the first click and the second (more a question than an issue) is that I want to play the animation when a command voice is said; do you know if there is any type event to do that?

Comment: @MarioJavierEugenioEstrada the snippet shoud be animating on each click. As for the voice commands, [here's an a-frame example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/speech_recognition.html) I've made from the official web speech [color example](https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/tree/master/speech-color-changer)

Comment: Thank yo so much, your examples really helped me a lot.

Comment: @MarioJavierEugenioEstrada glad i could help, If you like them feel free to star the repo